Get normal vector as a function of vector and its reflection off said plane
This question was asked almost nine years ago, and I found it because I'm making a robot that will direct a mirror to reflect light at a desired angle. I need a little more information than what the answer gave.
I want to find the unit normal vector for how to orient my mirror given a unit vector for where light is coming from, and the unit vector for where I want it to go.
The "forward" of this situation is just the classic vector reflection $$\mathbf r = \mathbf v-2(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)\mathbf n$$
What I want is the "inverse" then, where $\mathbf n$ is my dependent variable vector. I'm not satisfied with how the other question was answered. Sure, it feels like we get slightly closer by doing the following: $$(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)\mathbf n = \frac 1 2 (\mathbf v - \mathbf r)$$
But what now? I have no idea how to isolate $\mathbf n$.

Thank you guys for your help. For anyone reading this that wants to play with this idea, here you go: https://www.desmos.com/3d/9sajdstxzu

You were almost there, recall that $(\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n)$ is a scalar, and thus you can (assuming $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf n$ are not orthogonal) divide  by $(\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf n)$ and obtaining
$$\mathbf n = \frac{1}{2(\mathbf v\cdot \mathbf n)}(\mathbf v - \mathbf r)$$
and forgetting the norm of the vector, you obtain $$\mathbf n\propto (\mathbf v - \mathbf r)$$
This simply states that the normal to the mirror is the bisection of the incoming light ray and the reflected light ray.

I kind of get it now, but I guess what's confusing me is the fact that even though $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n$ is indeed a scalar, it's still a function of $\mathbf n$, which makes it not really feel isolated properly...

@HydroPage, the $v$ and $r$ are also interrelated via $n$, so the numerator is also kind of a function of $n$. It’s all the fraction at once that makes $n$ on the LHS isolated (although not necessarily uniquely identified unless there’s a restriction on the unit length).

@EgorLarionov So my understanding is that $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf n$ is just gonna be some number, regardless of what $\mathbf v$ or $\mathbf n$ actually equal, so it's clear that $\mathbf n$ and $\mathbf v - \mathbf r$ are linearly dependent, and since I only care about $\mathbf n$'s direction, I can normalize what it's linearly dependent with and go from there. This makes a lot of sense now.

Like the response in the linked question said, if you know the v and r, then r-v is collinear to the n and all you need to do is normalise it by dividing by the norm of r-v. Hence, $\mathbf{n}=\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{v}}{||\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{v}||}$.
